# "is starting on ..." Why is it Present?

Tags: present-tense, future, continuous-aspect

I have exercise to create sentences in Present Continuous but in one of them is. " The sales is starting on Monday". My question is about time used here, in my opinion this will happens only in future " On Monday" But the tense is Present so i'm little lost. What is different(in the meaning on structure)  between this and  Future Continuous like " The sales will be starting in Monday"

Comment: This has been dealt with earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use present verb forms to indicate that something is planned, scheduled or timetabled to happen in the future.

> The simple present is used to make statements about events at a time
> later than now, when the statements are based on present facts, and
> when these facts are something fixed like a time-table, schedule,
> calendar.
>
> My plane leaves at 18.00 tomorrow.

[Simple present for future events](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/)

> The present continuous is used to talk about arrangements for events
> at a time later than now. There is a suggestion that more than one
> person is aware of the event, and that some preparation has already
> happened.
>
> The sales are starting next Monday = The sales have been arranged and the stores have been or are being prepared.

[Present Continuous for future arrangements](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/present-continuous-future-arrangements/)

Comment: Thank you for answer. That is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: i didn't understand "are something fixed like" what does fixed, i only know fixed as repair. If i'm not wrong, that mean something like set,permanent

Comment: Fixed 2 (especially of a price, rate, or time) predetermined and not able to be changed:  ‘loans are provided for a fixed period’. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fixed

Answer (score 0):

**The present continuous tense** is often used with a future meaning. This tense form is used to talk about things that have already been decided or plans that have already been made.

Generally speaking, the present continuous tense is used to talk about our social or work plans. It is normally used with a future time reference.

What are you doing this weekend ? I am fixing the roof.

**The future continuous tense** is used to suggest that a future event will be in progress over a limited period of time in the future.

I will be spending one or two weeks in France.

Here the auxiliary ‘will’ indicates future whereas the continuous verb ‘be spending’ indicates continuity.

Use this tense form to suggest that an activity will be happening at a certain time in the future, and that this activity will last for a limited period of time.

Comment: Which shows how nonsensical it is to refer to form with "will" as "_the_ future tense".

Comment: I am not so sure about this, Colin. If I say that I will be spending one or two weeks in France, I am simply stating a fact that will take place in the future whereas if I say that I am fixing the roof, I express my present intention.

Comment: Sorry, @Aluna, I don't agree. _I will_ nearly always expresses an intention.

Comment: English doesn't really have a future tense. We need to make up a kind of future tense with auxiliary verbs like "will", but it's not really a future tense. Sometimes we don't even bother and stick with a present tense, with a similar understanding that it relates to something in the future.

Comment: @Colin Yes..."nearly" always, therefore referring to form with "will" as "the future tense" may not be so nonsensical                                                                                  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/will                                    http://cnycentral.com/news/local/its-raining-its-windy-it-will-be-snowing-slightly

Comment: OK, @Aluna. What tense is _I may go_? _I can go_? _I should go_? And if you reply that these are not tenses, how do you justify referring to one of these identical constructions as a tense, but not the others?

Comment: @Colin What's the problem ? You say "modality", I say "futurity"...                                                                                     Origin of "tense" :  1660–70; < Latin tēnsus past participle of tendere to stretch                                                                                                                           1275–1325; Middle English tens < Middle French < Latin tempus time    We are just looking at the same thing from a different angle as in the parable of the elephant.